# DotNet Interop -- is AllocHGlobal my only option

Tags: html, .net, interop

I inherited some old Interop code and wanted to update it for the newer guidance, as it uses StringBuilder.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices

I do not have access to the source code to the native method.

```cs
[DllImport(NativeLib, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int native_func(double input, StringBuilder result);

public string Convert(double input)
{
   var res = new StringBuilder();
   if (native_func(input, res) == 0)
      return res.ToString();
   throw ...;
}
```

I was able to convert things to manually use AllocateHGlobal instead of StringBuilder.

```cs
[DllImport(NativeLib, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int native_func(double input, IntPtr result);

public string Convert(input val)
{
   var res = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);
   // pretend we are calling Marshal.FreeHGlobal later...
   if (native_func(input, res) == 0)
      return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(res);
   throw ...;
}
```

But that's not the new ref/span/etc hotness.

However, no matter what I seem to try for the result parameter, I either get just the first character, or a System.AccessViolationException.
I've tried MemoryMarshal.GetReference, I've tried pinning, I've tried ref-ing, I've tried out-ing; whenever I'm trying to use a managed buffer, it just doesnt' work.

Are there scenarios where the new interop just doesn't work? Is AllocHGlobal the best I can do?

Comment: I think my problem is that i was trying to use Span<char>, I can get Span<byte> to work.

Comment: ```
[DllImport(NativeLib, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int native_func(double input, ref byte result);

public string Convert(input val)
{
   var res = stackalloc byte[100];
   if (native_func(input, ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(res)) == 0)
      return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(res.Slice(0, res.IndexOf((byte)0)));
   throw ...;
}
```